# Incorrect Highcharts colorAxis range

Tags: highcharts

I have a heatmap in Highcharts where the value range is from -1 to 100.  My low value color is `#FF0000`, which I expect to be mapped to the value of -1.  Instead, highcharts seems to be extending my color axis range so that a value of -25 would be shown as fully red, so my actual low value in the bottom left gets shown in a faint pink.  I have tried specifying `min` and `max` values for the `colorAxis`, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.  How can I get the color axis configured such that my -1 value will be rendered as red?

Here's my existing `colorAxis` configuration, which doesn't seem to be doing the right thing:

```
colorAxis: {
  stops: [
    [0, '#FF0000'],
    [0.25, '#FFFFFF'],
    [0.5, '#00FF00'],
    [0.75, '#FFFFFF'],
    [1, '#0000FF']
  ],
  min: -1,
  max: 100
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing this: https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/cLncce08/9/

In the below screenshot, for some reason the cursor is in the wrong place. It should be hovering over the bottom left cell in the heatmap where the value is -1.
[image: highcharts heatmap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` properties of the colorAxis that can eliminate the auto-extending axis.  When I added these and set them to false, my color range is what I expect.

```
colorAxis: {
  stops: [
    [0, '#FF0000'],
    [0.25, '#FFFFFF'],
    [0.5, '#00FF00'],
    [0.75, '#FFFFFF'],
    [1, '#0000FF']
  ],
  min: low,
  max: high,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false
},
```

The docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.startOnTick

[image]